# Postgres copy to insert data into table

Tags: postgresql

I have a text file in the below format. The first row is the header. The second row is the data.

```
"A"  "B"   "C"  "D" "E"   "F"   "G"   "H"   "I"    "J"      "K"   "L"        "M"   "N"       "O"       "P"       "Q"       "R"  "S"        "T"        "U"    "V"     "W"       "X"   "Y"       "Z"      "AA" "BB"     "CC" "DD" "EE"        "FF"      "GG"  "HH"   "II"     "JJ"   "KK"        "LL"       "MM"      "NN" "OO"
"1019311288593"  "3"     "3"     "3421D"       "1"     "2"     "3"     ""      "1500188"    "201802"        ""      ""      "11"    ""      ""      ""      ""      "9710" "121598630"    "1336332"    "60"    "20180213"      ""      ""      ""      "1"     ""      "00209500188021318"    ""      ""      ""      ""      "1215630"    ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      20180222        "green" 1
```

I am trying to use the following command to insert this data into a table -

```
\COPY service(<All columns listed above>) FROM 'test.txt' DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER
```

But I am getting this error -

```
`Missing data for column B.`
```

Comment: Are there tabs in the second line?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes.